# web scaping grab a image from javascript side

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I've tried grabbing the image from this:

```html
<img alt="Whoever Blinks First" title="Whoever Blinks First" src="https://secure2-images.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/whoever-blinks-first_1920x1080.webp?nvb=20200209184040&amp;nva=20200215184340&amp;hash=05599031bb49b7c1583cb" srcset="https://secure2-images.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/whoever-blinks-first_1920x1080.webp?nvb=20200209184040&amp;nva=20200215184340&amp;hash=05599031bb49b7c1583cb 1x, https://secure2-images-tushy.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/tushy-whoever-blinks-first_3840x2160.webp?nvb=20200209184040&amp;nva=20200215184340&amp;hash=072c8e8d26b8a88fd8672 2x" data-test-component="ProgressiveImageImage" class="sc-1egln9q-1 irBaDM">
```

with

```py
matches = soup.find_all('img')
print(matches.text)
```

I get only the "title" but no Links
what I must do for grab this?

thanks!

Comment: find_all() returns an array so you should use find_all('img')[0] or just find('img').

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```
soup.find_all('img').get('src');
```

Comment: matches = soup.find_all('img').get('src')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2080, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()? matches = soup.find('img').get('src')


print(len(matches)) >> 0

Comment: matches = soup.find('img')
print(matches)

Comment: I get this:
<img alt="Unexpected But Welcome" class="sc-1egln9q-1 dvwfIz" data-test-component="ProgressiveImageImage" src="" srcset="" title="Unexpected But Welcome"/>

Comment: But src="" is emtpy

Comment: the problem is: the images arent loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''<img alt="Whoever Blinks First" title="Whoever Blinks First" src="https://secure2-images.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/whoever-blinks-first_1920x1080.webp?nvb=20200209184040&amp;nva=20200215184340&amp;hash=05599031bb49b7c1583cb" srcset="https://secure2-images.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/whoever-blinks-first_1920x1080.webp?nvb=20200209184040&amp;nva=20200215184340&amp;hash=05599031bb49b7c1583cb 1x, https://secure2-images-tushy.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/tushy-whoever-blinks-first_3840x2160.webp?nvb=20200209184040&amp;nva=20200215184340&amp;hash=072c8e8d26b8a88fd8672 2x" data-test-component="ProgressiveImageImage" class="sc-1egln9q-1 irBaDM">
'''

doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
imgs = doc.imgs
print (imgs[0])
```

Result:

```
{
  'alt': 'Whoever Blinks First', 
  'title': 'Whoever Blinks First', 
  'src': 'https: //secure2-images.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/whoever-blinks-first_1920x1080.webp?nvb=20200209184040&nva=20200215184340&hash=05599031bb49b7c1583cb', 
  'srcset': 'https://secure2-images.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/whoever-blinks-first_1920x1080.webp?nvb=20200209184040&nva=20200215184340&hash=05599031bb49b7c1583cb 1x, https://secure2-images-tushy.ssl-cdn.com/videoimages/101323/mainLandscape/1568806239343/tushy-whoever-blinks-first_3840x2160.webp?nvb=20200209184040&nva=20200215184340&hash=072c8e8d26b8a88fd8672 2x', 
  'data-test-component': 'ProgressiveImageImage', 
  'class': 'sc-1egln9q-1 irBaDM', 
  'tag': 'img'
}
```

Here's an example of SimplifiedDoc: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples